# Health check failed when service is still running

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, sentry, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google health check in order to send request to my flask client to make sure my service is alive. 
the same route in flask client sends request to two more flask clients to make sure the other two is also alive.

For some reason the request sometimes fails when the service is still running.

I tries to figure out why but there is nothing in my services logs that indicates that something happened and on most cases it works fine.

This is my code:

```
    #GET /health_check//
    def get(self):
        try:
            for service in INTERNAL_SERVICES_HEALTH_CHECKS:
                client = getattr(all_clients, service + '_client')
                response = client.get('g_health_check')
        except Exception, e:
            sentry_client.captureMessage('health check failed for '+env+ ' environment. error log:' + repr(e))
            return output_json({'I\'m Not fine!':False}, requests.codes.server_error)

        return output_json({'I\'m fine!':True}, requests.codes.ok)
```

If anyone has any suggestions I will be happy to try and fix it.